# Rails: Virtually update attribute on record call for :through tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to know if it's possible to achieve something like this: `Product.last(cost: 100)`

Where it will return the product, but with a virtually updated cost attribute (so there is no change to the database).

Here is the scenario, maybe someone can tell me a more elegant way of doing what I am trying to: I have three models, `Order`, `LineItem`, and `Product`. LineItem belongs_to Order and Order has_many LineItems. LineItem is polymorphic. Order has_many products through LineItems (but Product does not belong to LineItem or Order). Order.products << Product.first works as I would expect, the line item is assigned the product and the order will save correctly. However.. Each line item in an order has a cost attribute that by default inherits from the cost of the product. I want to modify the cost attribute on LineItem without modifying it on Product (i.e. a Product has some sort of temporary discount on it that adjusts the price). Am I going about this in the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood your question, but you you can do this to get an object and change one of its attribute's value locally:

```
   @product =
      Product.last.tap do |product|
        product.cost = 100
        product.readonly! # to ensure you won't persist this change
      end
```